# Linux permission for group users to delete files and directory

Tags: linux

I need to grant users in a group to delete the directory and files inside the directory. I have added all the users to group named "fileHandlers". I want all users in this group to have permission to create files or folders and delete them.

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data fileHandlers 4096 Nov 26 13:13 7005C0FA85E4A0B445E77C126EEB8056
```

In the above example only www-data is able to delete this files. how can i extend it for all the users in group "fileHandlers"

Comment: Use ACL or just grant them write permission: `chmod -R g+w whatever`

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the users (i.e., the group)
write permission to the directory:

```
chmod g+w dirname
```

For them to be able to delete the directory itself,
they need write permission to the *parent* directory.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the problem with following commands

```
 chgrp -R fileHandlers attachments/
 chmod -R g+w attachments/
 find attachments -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
 find attachments -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```